# Installing RSense for VIM

Tags: ruby, linux, vim, text-editor

I am trying to install [`RSense`](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html) for vim in fedora. I read [this manual](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html). I downloaded the tar ball of rsense and extracted it. Then I copied it to the `root/opt` directory as given on that page. Then I made a directory `vim/plugin` in the opt directory and copied the `rsense.vim` in the plugin directory. But when I write `:RSenseVersion` in the vim editor,I get a message that the command is not recognized.What have I missed ?

Till now I have not installed `vim-ruby` plugin as staged on the [documentation page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/). What is this plugin meant for ? Can't `RSense` alone solve my purpose of writing a neat ruby code with auto-completion,code hinting ?

[image: Copied that plugin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you didn't [read the manual](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html#Install_Vim_Plugin).

Once all the dependancies are dealt with you must put the plugin in `~/.vim/plugin`.

As for the differences between vim-ruby and RSense, I don't do Ruby so I don't know for sure. Looking quickly at their doc, it looks like they are very different in scope and have slightly overlapping features. I'd install both: vim-ruby for all the low-level Vim tuning and RSense for its supposed code intelligence.

But I have a feeling none of them will help you write "neat" ruby code. Only *your* programing/ruby skills will.

Comment: what is the difference between `~/.vim.plugin` and `vim.plugin` ? I did the second one

Comment: The difference between me typing correctly and me typing incorrectly. Sorry. See my edit.

Comment: aah ! what is the difference between `~/.vim/plugin` and `vim/plugin` ?

Comment: `~/.vim/plugin` is the normal location for Vim plugins. `~/` is a shortcut for your `/home/username/` directory, `~/.vim/` is an "invisible" (because of the dot) directory and `~/.vim/plugin/` is another directory under `~/.vim/`. Neither `~/.vim/` nor `~/.vim/plugin/` are created by default: you must do that yourself as per the instructions in the RSense manual. `vim/plugin` would be a `plugin` directory under a `vim` "normal" (not "invisible") directory under the current directory, whatever that is. Just follow the instructions in the manual, they are clear, quick and easy.

Comment: can you please explain me [what do they do after copying `RSense` in a the directory ?](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html#Install_RSense) I am a novice for linux

Comment: I don't think I'm able to explain it more clearly than what's in the documentation, specially in a comment here. You should learn the basics before doing all that or get ready to spend a lot of time here.